# Is it possible to select text from multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

Using a java script, you can make a selection. This will be equivalent to selecting with the mouse cursor. The code that I added to the question makes a selection of each element inside the container you click on, but the previous selection disappears. Can this be changed?

```js
const selectElement = (element) =>
{
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(element);
  
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener('click', (event) => 
{
  const x = event.pageX;
  const y = event.pageY;

  selectElement(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Code snippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="firstElement">
        First element text
      </div>

      <div id="secondElement">
        Second element text
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
For better understanding, I added a second snippet that does what I would like to get, but without using a `window.getSelection().addRange()`.

```js
const selectElement = (element) =>
{
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  element.style.color = 'white';
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener('click', (event) => 
{
  const x = event.pageX;
  const y = event.pageY;

  selectElement(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Code snippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="firstElement">
        First element text
      </div>

      <div id="secondElement">
        Second element text
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `selection.removeAllRanges()` sounds like it removes the existing selection. Perhaps that is what you want to change?

Comment: Tip: rather than obtaining the element at the cursor position, the event argument contains the source element.

Comment: Are you asking if you can create **discontiguous** selections?

Comment: @andrew without `selection.removeAllRanges()` selection doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Dai, i updated the question.

Comment: do you mean text highlight or text selection as the second code in your question only highlights the text.

Comment: @Andam I mean what the second code does, but using a `window.getSelection().addRange()`. In the first code, if you select the second text, then the selection from the first text will disappear, and if you select the first text, then the selection from the second text will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accpording to the other answer and MDN it only works in FF.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70175542/4860688

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange#example

But, here is how to do it in FF:

Moving focus and/or clicking on elements typically (always?) removes the previous selection as per pretty standard UI selection behaviour.

If you wanted to retain the previous selection range(s) then you will need to store them separately and re-add them to the window's selection ranges.

Obviously this is counter intuitive to any user expectation but I'm not going to presume anything about why you want this :)

```js
var ranges = [];
const selectElement = (element) =>
{
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(element);
  ranges.push(range);
  
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  ranges.forEach(r => selection.addRange(r));
}

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener('click', (event) => 
{
  selectElement(event.target);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Code snippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="firstElement">
        First element text
      </div>

      <div id="secondElement">
        Second element text
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that if you click outside your container div, the selections are cleared - this is the standard behaviour and since your event listener is only on the div, the selections are not restored. If you want to change that, move your event listener to the body.

Comment: Hm.. I ran your code snippet, but the selection doesn't work.

Comment: @pibocik125 his code is for normal selection not auto selection

Comment: I didn't know it only worked in Firefox (which is what I use). Although your code does not work in Firefox. Strange that the accepted answer is that you can only do it in FF but does not say how to do it. Oh well. :)